# Ajax call opening too many connections?

Tags: ajax, post, connection, pageload

I've got a small problem concerning my webpage that I'm updating using ajax. When I stay on my page for a while (an hour or so) it will stop loading and I can't display any of my pages in the browser. I've only started having this problem since I added this (simplified) javascript to my page:

```
var interval;

interval = setInterval('UpdateComs()',5000);


function FuncGo() {

  $.post('data.php', { profile: pid }, function(data) {

    $('.holder').html(data);

  });

}
```

Since my server isn't down and this can't be the problem, I was thinking that this might be caused by too many connections? Could the above be opening more than one connection?

And if it does should I somehow close them? 

 Sorry for all the questions but I'm not too familiar with how connections work.. Thanks for any help or ideas

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suspect a random error (connection gets behind due to network traffic, maybe a timeout) that stops the setInterval.  Always pass an annonomus function (not a string) to setTimeout or setInterval and only call the next function after the completion of the prior one.

```
function UpdateComs() {
 $.ajax({
  type: "POST",
  url: 'data.php'
  data: {profile:pid},
  async: true,
  cache: false,
  timeout: 10000,
  success: function(data){
    $('.holder').html(data);
    setTimeout(function(){UpdateComs(); },5000);
  },
  error: function(XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown){
    //do what you want with the error
    setTimeout(function(){UpdateComs(); },5000);
  }
 });
}
```

Comment: Thanks I'll try implementing that in the future :) I asked my web host about it and they said it was probably because my IP address had accessed the server more than 2000 times in 24 hours, which caused an ip ban for the page. Does that mean there were 2000 different connections or that it accessed data through one connection 2000 times and is that something to worry about? If I get paid webhosting then i can avoid this limitation.. Thanks for the reply :)

Comment: Note that to send the next request, you probably want to use the `complete()` callback and not repeat the `setTimeout()` call in the `success` and `error` callbacks.